# how to run a system command in xcode in background

Tags: xcode, macos, shell, ffmpeg, system

I need to run an ffmpeg command with this paramater: -i 'url_of_input_here'. so using NSTask with parameter array as such does not work:

```
NSString * ffm_address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'udp://%d.%d.%d.%d:%d?fifo_size=1000000000&overrun_nonfatal=1'",addr_1,addr_2,addr_3,addr_4,portFFM];
[task setArguments:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-f", @"mpegts", @"-i", ffm_address, @"-re",@"-y",@"-strict",@"experimental",@"-vcodec", @"copy", @"-f", @"mp4", @"video.mp4", nil]];
```

since the quotes are being processed in such a way that ffmpeg thinks that the udp://.... address is a file

XCode has system() function that lets me execute system commands, but when i run the ffmpeg command it stalls the process (since ffmpeg is processing a stream):

```
char ffm_cmd[512];
sprintf(ffm_cmd,"ffmpeg -f mpegts -i 'udp://%d.%d.%d.%d:%d?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1' -re -y -strict experimental -vcodec copy -f mp4 video.mp4",addr_1,addr_2,addr_3,addr_4,portFFM);
    system(ffm_cmd);
```

how can i run the system() command in the background so it doesn't stall the rest of the app? I would rather not use a separate thread, but start the ffmpeg and move on with the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way to do it! simply add & at the end of the command:

```
   char ffm_cmd[512];
    sprintf(ffm_cmd,"ffmpeg -f mpegts -i 'udp://%d.%d.%d.%d:%d?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1' -re -y -strict experimental -vcodec copy -f mp4 video.mp4 &",addr_1,addr_2,addr_3,addr_4,portFFM);
    system(ffm_cmd);
```